# Clear gsi command line Gambit

Tags: scheme, gambit

Anyone knows how to clear the command line in gsi Gambit of Scheme,like in the normal command line we use --> clear ,is there any command for that in gsi Gambit of Scheme? Is there any better IDE for Scheme? Thanks :)

Comment: Racket is very, very good ;)

Answer (score 2):

The gsi REPL handles many of the readline keybindings.  So you can use ctrl-U to delete the text before the cursor and ctrl-K to delete the text after the cursor.